# Dynamic DOM Manipulation Function: How To Improve It, Should I Be Using It, & What's It Doing Here?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, scope

Okay, so I have a fairly thorough understanding of programming (Bachelors in CS), but Web Development is an absolute nightmare, and no one I've asked can give me any *real* information on what I should be doing here. Most of them go, "oh, look at that. nifty." and that's the end of it.

I've been doing a lot of pet projects with dynamic content, and to speed the process up, I wrote a function to create and insert elements into the DOM. It's fairly straightforward, and not exactly elegant, but gets the job done.

As the title says, I'm looking for ways to improve this, perhaps a better established practice, and then I have a question about implementing it.

Here's the code:

```
app.newDOMObject = function (type, attributes, values, parentNode, innerHTML) {
    if (type) {
        var element = document.createElement(type);
        if (attributes && values) {
            if (attributes.length == values.length && attributes.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
                    element.setAttribute(attributes[i], values[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        if (innerHTML) {
            element.innerHTML = innerHTML;
        }
        if (parentNode) {
            parentNode.appendChild(element);    
        }
        return element;
    }
}
```

and then when I want to use it, I do either:

```
var thing = app.newDOMObject("div", ["id"], ["thing"], document.body, "thing1");
```

or just

```
app.newDOMObject("div", ["id"], ["thing"], document.body, "thing2");
```

depending on if I need to reference it later or not.

My last question is: What happens to the returned element with thing2, since I'm not assigning it to a variable? I should obviously know this, but is it cluttering up global? Does it know I'm not using it, and just drop it? There's no prototyping or anything, and it's just returning an element that's already in the DOM. Where does it go and why does this work without an error? :/

I'm sure I should read a book on advanced JavaScript mechanics, but I don't actually know what I'm asking, and five minutes Googling keywords like "expression" and "declaration" and "returning to not a variable" were about as helpful as you can imagine.

And most posts I did find on the issue all recommended templating libraries, but I'd like to avoid them if I can.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Thanks for the help!
-Tyler

Comment: +1 for the good formatting!

Comment: You should search for memory management in javascript. Basically, it doesn't matter if you return a value which doesn't get assigned. In your case, because that value is already assigned to some other object, there shouldn't be a cost in doing so. For your concerns on code improvement, perhaps asking on the code review stackexchange would help?

Comment: Perhaps you would need a more advanced function which check for correctness wrt the document type: normally, you cannot add any kind of tag to any other.

Answer (score 1):

Not storing a returned value has similar effects as in other languages, you just don't keep it anywhere and in most cases it's just gone.

In your case it will be persisted anyway, since you append it to you parameter parentNode, thus it more or less depends on where that parentNode came from and what you do with it after that.

In your example function calls you append to document body, which means it will be persisted in the DOM of the current document / website. You don't need to hold a reference to it to use it later, you could also traverse the DOM and fetch a new reference to the node.

For some inspiration regarding DOM manipulation I'd recommend taking a look at the jQuery framework and its [Manipulation API section](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).